# If beings with superhuman abilities lived today, could they and social justice cope?

Tags: politics, super-powers

There's a group of beings who look like humans but who are better by a factor of two in everything except lifespan - their average lifespan is half that of humans.

Effectively they live and die twice as quickly. They can run faster, think quicker, EDIT Their IQ's appear to be higher but that's simply because they think quicker.

There is a social justice movement to prevent inequality of pay. What's a good strategy for the supernatural beings?

1. Use their powers to take over society and squash social justice
2. Argue that they should get promoted sooner and paid more than humans because they will die sooner and therefore have shorter careers but achieve twice as much per hour
3. Work fewer hours but achieve the same as mortals for the same pay
4. Something else (that presumably they have already thought of because of their superior IQ's)

Comment: if they have twice the IQ shouldn't they get paid more because they are smarter

Comment: I'm not sure "social justice" copes - I think that's a discussion for Politics SE. I'd say "go to a piece work contractor strategy, forget hourly and salary pay"

Comment: There are different kinds of equality. Please elaborate. I assume you  mean equality of outcome. In that case, well, just check out how such ideology is usually dealt with (pretty easily btw). I feel like you could easily answer the question yourself if you work out what the anti inequality group actualy campaigns for and research about people fighting for whatever concept of equality you want. Research is strongly encouraged here. The problem doesn't change one bit with your superpowers. People are already not equal to begin with

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem here actually is. If they're genius scientists they'll be paid like genius scientists, if they're star athletes they'll be paid like start athletes, if they're amazing actors they'll be paid like amazing actors. What inequality are you expecting? That they *wouldn't* be paid according to their abilities? (also, they live half as long but non-super people are 'mortals'?)

Comment: Seems to be a question of ageism rather than pay for ability. Their gripe is that, yes, they're being paid an appropriate wage for their abilities but that this wage is half what it should be because "ordinary" people live twice as long and thus earn a real wage 2x what they earn. If an "ordinary" physician (family medicine) is paid £175000 per annum for 25 years, that £3.5 million (take away 60pc for taxes and professional insurance to get closer to the real number). The "superordinary" is arguing that her wage should be £350k because she'll only be working for 12 1/2 years before retiring.

Comment: @elemtilas - They're earning less in a "real" wage **but** also paying out far less in "real" costs for things like rent, insurances (health, car, etc), utility bills, probably education - based on duration, years studying - and a host of other nearly-fixed, time dependent factors.  Maybe they will buy twice the groceries, if their metabolism is really 2x, but probably won't wear out clothes 2x as fast.  And even though you mentioned taxes, I don't think they scale quite linearly ('s why there's brackets, not a simple calculation) and there are a number of year-dependent tax factors, too.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt any social movement toward **equal pay** without regard to any other factor will ever exist, or could survive long if it did.

Would people still go to college and become doctors, lawyers, engineers and other types of highly educated professionals if there is no pay incentive whatsoever, and they will earn exactly as much as a high school dropout washing dishes?

Yes, I know some people don't do it for the money. But most people consider a "good living" and a salary of six figures or more at least ONE of the reasons they are busting their butt in college to get their terminal degrees (PhD, JD, MD). (In academics called 'terminal' because there is no *higher* academic degree for the field in question. Of course *multiple* terminal degrees can be earned; a person can be a PhD, Juris Doctor and Medical Doctor simultaneously.)

Absolutely equal pay for all is roughly equivalent to communism, and communism fails, not necessarily for corruption, but because it lacks incentives for workers to make any effort. They cannot get ahead no matter **what** they do, so being human, they quickly fall into doing as little as they will be **allowed** to do and still get paid, and resort to outside-the-system means of actually getting ahead. Black market trading, under-the-table labor and services (perhaps including prostitution or pimping for prostitutes), drug production and sales, gambling, and so on. With organization, these can turn into a mafia.

In America at least a social movement for "equal pay for equal work" already exists, so does a social movement for a "living wage". I agree with both of them, for what its worth. But superhuman people could easily argue that "equal pay for equal work", by extension, means they **deserve** to be paid double pay for doing the work of **two** people.

Answer (score 1):

We already have humans with a great diversity of lifespans.  A lot of people can guess they are likely to live longer or shorter lives based on genetics.  Others have been diagnosed with a life-threatening disease (like cancer) and know they only have a few years (or less) before it catches up with them (and usually they stop being able to work a while before they die).  And many people with certain disabilities know they have limited lifespan.

Would we promote someone with Type I diabetes faster than someone without because their lifespan is probably shorter?  Should someone with a slow-growing but ultimately fatal cancer be paid more to make up for the years she'll miss out on?  Not only is this not done now, it's not something any activist advocates for.

If these folks are much faster thinkers then the changes will be in education.  They can have their own schools or do independent study so they graduate a lot faster than the standard student (think Doogie Howser).

Post-graduate studies would be faster too.  For promotions based on merit, they are likely to get there faster as well, because they'll be able to pass tests or learn on the job faster.

They can also enter higher paying fields more frequently than the average human, because of their ability to learn and adapt more quickly.

In other words, they already have advantages.  So why would you want to give them even more?  Sure, they might set themselves up to have even more privilege than they already do, should they obtain that level of power, but no society is going to hand it to them.